# How can I read file from classes directory in my WAR?

Tags: java, file, classpath, war

I need to read text file from the classpath in Java WAR application. How can I read it as InputStream. File is located in /WEB-INF/classes/ folder, but when I use following code, it just returns null.

```
InputStream input = servletContext.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("my_filename.txt");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prefix it with a forward slash to denote the root of the classpath:

```
getResourceAsStream("/my_filename.txt")
```

Alternatively, you can use the `serlvetContext.getResourceAsStream(..)` which looks for resources relative to the context root. So classes would be `/WEB-INF/classes`.

Comment: I tried with that too, but it still returns null. Does servletContext have right classloader or how can I be sure that I'm using right classloader ?

Comment: @newbie: . One trick is to write a file with the same name at the same location, if you can't read, and then see where exactly the program has written the file.

Comment: @newbie is the file for sure there? with the same name, extension and case?

Comment: It started to work when I added /WEB-INF/classes/ to start of path. Thanx for help!